# Do-while statement Java

Tags: java, loops, return, do-while

I am new to programming. I have difficulties understanding this bit of code:

```
public static boolean onCampus(String name)
{
    boolean invalidResponse = true;
    do{
    System.out.println("Is "+name+ " living on campus? (yes/no)");
    String response = in.nextLine();
    if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        return true;
    else if (response.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
        return false;
    else
        System.out.println("Invalid response.");
    } while(invalidResponse);
    return false;
}
```

What I don't get is where is `invalidResponse` assigned `false` in case the user enter an acceptable response? And what is that last `return false;`? Why is it after the do-while statement?

Comment: The last `return false;` is unreachable code.  The compiler doesn't know that `invalidResponse` never gets updated, but if you changed it to `do { ... } while (true);` you'd get a compile error from the last return statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is somewhat of an anti-pattern - the loop is infinite, and will never terminate "properly". Instead, once you get a valid response, you'll simply call `return`, and exit the method, thus terminating the loop.

The `return false` after the loop is a compilation limitation. In java, if the method returns a value, every conceivable branch must contain a `return` statement (or a `throw` statement, to be precise). In compile time, Java doesn't "know" that the loop may never be terminated, so it forces you to have a return statement in that branch (i.e., assuming the loop terminates without the `if` or `else if` branches being executed).

Comment: Thanks. Is this the best way to write this method or using other loop statements would have been more appropriate?

Comment: @MarcoGreselin it's a pretty common idiom. I'd inline the `invalidResponse` variable, but it's a matter of taste more than anything.

Answer (score 3):

The last "return false;" is just there so that the compiler will not complain, it is unreachable code. Because your return type is boolean, your code must return true or false for all cases. "invalidResponse" is never assigned to false so your loop will run infinitely until the user enters either yes or no in which case it returns the boolean and exits the function.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `in` represents a static `Scanner` variable.

The loop is intentionally infinite; `invalidResponse` will never be set `false`.

Instead, the `return` lines are the ways out of the loop, assuming the value of `"yes"` or `"no"` is entered.

The final `return false;` is necessary for compilation purposes, but will never be reached.

Of note, however, I'm a fan of a single `return`, using constants as the first half of an equals, and removing case sensitivity once, and would re-code this as:

```
public static boolean onCampus(String name) {

    boolean response = false;

    do {

        System.out.println("Is " + name + " living on campus? (yes/no)");
        String input = in.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        response = "yes".equals(input);

        if (response || "no".equals(input)) {

            break;  // exit the loop

        } else {

            System.out.println("Invalid response.");
        }

    } while (!response);

    return response;
}
```